# Delete slash at end only in .php files

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Does it have an access code that killed the slash at the end of the URL?

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ /$1 [NE,R=302,L]
```

How to do something like that:

> lala.php/

to

> lala.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove trailing slash after `.php` you can use this simple rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+\.php)/$ /$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```